# MapView.moveCamera() show always the same camera

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Hi guys my problem is about mapView. I want to set the camera to a new position but when i call SetNewPosition the log tell to me that coordinates are  changed but the mapview on the screen shows always the same place.

```
public void SetNewPosition(double log,double lat)
      {
      Log.i("Current position",""+mappa.getCameraPosition());

      LatLng latLng= new LatLng(log, lat);
      CameraUpdate cameraUpdate= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
      mappa.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
      mappa.clear();
      map.invalidate();
      map.postInvalidate();
      Log.i("Changed position",""+mappa.getCameraPosition());

  }
```

Can anyone tell where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you may want to use :

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng (log, lat);

LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder ();
builder.include (latLng);

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build ();

CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds (bounds, 0);

googleMap.animateCamera (cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. generates a java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.  Either wait until layout has occurred or use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) which allows you to specify the map's dimensions.

Comment: i tried to use  newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int)  but it does't work to

Comment: Can you share more code? 
Normally you can't call `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds (bounds, 0);` and you should call the 4 arguments method instead.

Comment: excuse me..i've added the other code to your answers wrongly...i wanted to add it to my question.. but there is the code

Comment: @P.Carlino, ah... so you're using a `MapView` you shouldn't. You should use a `MapFragment`, using a MapFragment, the Google Maps api handles the layout rendering etc....
Let me know if you need help on this.

Comment: Ok i'll try thanks for all.. if it work s write in another answer so i'll rate